# Store mapping-logic from adapters to db

Tags: javascript, typescript, service, nestjs

I´m building a nestjs-service where I´ve to normalize several JSON-messages from different origins. Every origin has a different JSON structure. At the moment I´m using an adapter in Typescript, but it would be better if I could store those translation maps in a database. Do you have any ideas on this issue or maybe a link to an example? But first let me show what I have so far:

the Normalizer function in my service:

```
private normalizeMessage(event: any, driverId: string): MessageDto {
        const adapter = this.getAdapter(driverId);
        return {
            event: adapter.adapt(event)
        }
    }

getAdapter(driverId: string): MessageAdapter {
        let adapter = this.adapterMap.get(driverId);
        if (!adapter) {
            switch (driverId) {
                case 'Granny Smith':
                    adapter = new GrannySmith_Adapter();
                    break;

                case 'Cox Orange':
                    adapter = new CoxOrange_Adapter();
                    break;

                case 'Golden Delicious':
                    adapter = new GoldenDelicious_Adapter();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (!adapter) {
                throw new Error('Adapter not implemented: ' + driverId);
            }
            this.adapterMap.set(driverId, adapter);
        }
        return adapter;
    }
```

the interface of the adapter:

```
export interface MessageAdapter {
    adapt(event): NormalizedEventDto;
}
```

one expl. adapter:

```
import { NormalizedEventDto } from "../../../../../../model/dist";
import { MessageAdapter } from "../message-adapter";

export class GrannySmith_Adapter implements MessageAdapter {
    adapt(event): NormalizedEventDto {

        return {
            appleName: event.apple.name,    // here I map the individual nodes of the given JSON on my normalized JSON
            appleLocation: event.apple.location,
            [...],
            original: event
        };
    }
}
```

The great disadvantage of this method is, that I´ve to edit the service every time I need new adapters for new apple sorts. So it would be nice to store them in a database...

Regards, Dom

Comment: Sure, you can store source code in your database. It's not a good idea though, in fact it's a maintenance nightmare. This doesn't have anything to do with TypeScript

Comment: Hello AluanHaddad, but to store source code was not the goal. The normalize-method ist called by an iteration over a driver array, so I could additionally store a JSONB-Field with the translation map (return value of given adapter). But I don´t know how to make the adapter kind of generic. Another idea would be, if I had a folder, where I just have to put new "drivers" (maps) and restart the service for maintenance - also there I need hints. Thx

Comment: When you said store translation maps in the database I thought you were referring to storing the logic that normalizes the various structures which would be source code. It's not a bad idea to have a folder with adapters, maybe resolved by convention to adapt one thing or another. I would advise you to get rid of your class and your interface and just use plain old functions for this kind of thing.